# Exploitation of Resource Packages in Java

Tags: malware, exploit, virus

I understand this might be a usual question but I thought it'd be interesting to get people's feedback regardless as this relates to security.

In games, in particular I am thinking about Minecraft, there is this functionality called resource packs. In addition there are also shader packs but I will get to those later. The resource packs I am referring to aren't the ones that come with an installer, but simply the zip files containing various text files to customize the look of the game.

Are there possible sources of exploitation that could occur from these zip files being loaded into the game? What kind of Java exploits could hackers potentially use to gain access to your system. I'm thinking about this from a vulnerability point of view.

A second feature people will also often add is a pack called a shader. Again the shaders are the ones that are NOT installed on the system using an exe file. These are simply zip files loaded into the game using a shader loader such as OptiFine. Are there possible security issues with this as well?

The resource packs (texture packs) and shader packs are downloaded from third party websites, generally from the author's website. Virus total scans of zip files show nothing. Would there still be concerns?

Thanks!